# Want to get last value using regex having multiple slashes

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
//abc.net/v1/hello/16546515646/abcdefgh
```

I want to get the value `abcdefgh` from above using regex.

I am using `hello(\/.*)(\/.*)`, but it gives me the string `hello/16546515646/abcdefgh`

Can anybody provide the regex that how to get only  `abcdefgh`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
[^\/]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE7dQ0/2)

Breakup:

```
[^\/]+    # match anything that is not /
$         # followed by end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

Here pattern that match letters from end:

```
'/\/\w+$/'
```